# How many random binary vectors are needed so that their subset sums generate all possible binary vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability

I'm interested to know how many random binary vectors are needed so that their subset sums generate all possible binary vectors.

Namely, let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$. We say $A \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}$ subset-sum-generates all binary vectors if for all $v \in \{0,1\}^n$, there exists $w \in \{0,1\}^m$ such that $w^\top A=v$.
What is the probability that $A$ subset-sum-generates all binary vectors when sampled uniformly at random over $\{0,1\}^{m \times n}$, as a function of $n$ and $m$?

Clearly, if $m<n$, the probability is $0$. I guess that when $m$ starts to be really large (e.g. $m\geq 2^n$), the probability starts to grow, in particular because there is a decent chance that the set of rows of the matrix $A$ contains all possible binary vectors. I'm particularly interested by value where $m$ is a polynomial of $n$.

Comment: with a polynomial $m$ it is very low, since vectors with linear combinations that are still binary are not statistically probable